# What are pros and cons of Amazon S3 vs Amazon EBS?

Tags: amazon

For websites/applications and eCommerce, which storage solution is more desirable and why?

I'm very new to Amazon Cloud Services so I need some direction here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://www.cloudiquity.com/2009/03/differences-between-s3-and-ebs/) might help you ([cached article here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3agsXwglgWNi8J%3awww.cloudiquity.com/2009/03/differences-between-s3-and-ebs/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)).

In brief, S3 is general storage whereas EBS is for mounting volumes attached to EC2 instances. S3 is more reliable than EBS. If you use EBS then you should backup to S3 periodically.

Comment: BINGO,  its Alfasin again, well thankyou very much :) Im very happy now

Comment: you're most welcome!